# What is a tau parameter?

Tags: interpretation, nonlinear-regression

I am reading weight loss charts, they state "tau 146 days" and "tau 110 days".  What is tau in this context?

[image]

The charts are here: http://bit.ly/1xT253g

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty hokey to me.  They appear to be claiming that their new diet plan will make people loose weight according to an [exponential decay process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay).  They are treating pounds above a "target weight" as analogous to radioactive atoms in a hunk of uranium.  The average time that one of these pounds will last before being lost is $\tau$ (tau), which is equal to the reciprocal of the decay rate $\lambda$.  It is just another way of parameterizing the exponential decay model.